# Find where two curves intersect

Tags: trigonometry

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ok2M6.jpg

I drew this amazing diagram to demonstrate what I'm trying to calculate. If you couldn't tell, these are walls and towers of a castle. In order to 'close' the castle, I need to find out the  point at which the two red lines intersect, so that a tower can be made to connect both the walls together.

For the sake of this problem, the size of the walls are fixed so all three side lengths are known. This means you can use the cosine law to find out the angle of one of the rotating walls from the static wall. However, I tried implementing it but I can't get it working properly.

Here's the code:

```
function FindIntersection(vector Tower1, vector Tower2, float Wall1, float Wall2, out vector Point)
{
    local float S1; // Length of side between the two towers.
    local float S2; // Length of the first wall.
    local float S3; // Length of the second wall.
    local float CosA, A; // Stores the angle between S1 and S2.
    local vector Vec, Vec2;

    Tower1.Z = 0; // Make sure the towers are level.
    Tower2.Z = 0;
    S1 = VSize(Tower2 - Tower1); // Get the first side length.
    S2 = Wall1; // Get the second side length.
    S3 = Wall2; // Get the third side length.

    `log("---------- S1: " $ S1 $ " S2: " $ S2 $ " S3: " $ S3 $ " -----------");

    // Perform cosine law to get angle between S1 and S2.
    CosA = (Sq(S2) + Sq(S1) - Sq(S3)) / (2 * S2 * S1);
    A = ACos(CosA);

    `log("--------------------- " $ A*57.2957795131 $ " ---------------------");

    // Get a vector angle between up and S1.
    Vec = Normal(Tower2-Tower1);

    // Get a vector angle between S1 and S2.
    Vec2.X = Cos(A);
    Vec2.Y = Sin(A);
    Vec2.Z = 0;
    Vec2 = Normal(Vec2);

    // Determine the location of the new tower.
    Point = Tower1 + Normal(Vec+Vec2) * S2;
}
```

I'm almost certain that the inputs are correct. I know I'm not accounting for angles over 90 degrees and that's probably a problem but I really don't know how to proceed from here. Thank you for any help!

Comment: i think you're more likely to get your answer in math.stackexchange, despite the fact that you're implementing it in code.

Comment: They are not lines but arcs. That makes a huge difference in the calculation.

Comment: You're right, but that's irrelevant. It's a triangle and I just need to find out where one of the corners is.

Comment: You should probably change the title to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the angle `A` for triangle sides `S1`, `S2` and `S3`. You can use the [law of cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) to get

```
A = ACOS( (S1*S1+S2*S2-S3*S3)/(2*S1*S2) )
```

The the coordinates of the vertex are found if you know the orientation of the base wall (S1).

```
TH = ATAN( (Tower2.Y-Tower1.Y)/(Tower2.X-Tower1.X) )
Tower3.X = S2*COS(A+TH)
Tower3.Y = S2*SIN(A+TH)
```

Comment: Better yet, use the `ATAN2()` function in place of `ATAN`.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a spin:

```
function FindIntersection(vector Tower1, vector Tower2, float Wall1, float Wall2, out vector Point)
{
    local float S1; // Length of side between the two towers.
    local float S2; // Length of the first wall.
    local float S3; // Length of the second wall.
    local float CosA, A; // Stores the angle between S1 and S2.
    local vector Vec1;

    Tower1.Z = 0; // Make sure the towers are level.
    Tower2.Z = 0;
    S1 = VSize(Tower2 - Tower1); // Get the first side length.
    S2 = Wall1; // Get the second side length.
    S3 = Wall2; // Get the third side length.

    `log("---------- S1: " $ S1 $ " S2: " $ S2 $ " S3: " $ S3 $ " -----------");

    // Perform cosine law to get angle between S1 and S2.
    CosA = (Sq(S2) + Sq(S1) - Sq(S3)) / (2 * S2 * S1);
    A = ACos(CosA);

    `log("---------------------  Angle in degrees" $ (A* 180.f) / M_PI $ " ---------------------");

    // Get a vector angle between up and S1.
    Vec1 = Normal(Tower2-Tower1);

    // rotate the normalized vector around axis (0,1,0) (assuming Unreals co-ordinate system is x,y,z and Y is UP
    local quat quatRot =  QuatFromAxisAndAngle( Vect(0,0,1), -A ); //angle accepted in radians NOTE: Could just be A instead of -A, depends on which way the point will rotate

    local vector corectedS2Vector = Normal ( QuatRotateVector ( quatRot , Vec1 ));

     // Determine the location of the new tower.
    Point = Tower1 + corectedS2Vector * S2;
}
```

Comment: This worked brilliantly, thanks! I didn't even know UDK had these functions.